# How to populate a NOT NULL field in a trigger?

Tags: sql, triggers, constraints, advantage-database-server

I am using Advantage Database Server 10.

I've got a table with 2 fields:

FieldA String Not Null
FieldB String Not Null

Now I need a trigger which populates fieldB with the value of FieldA when inserting a new record.

My intention was to use a "before insert" or a "instead of insert" trigger with the following code:

```
UPDATE test set test2 = ( SELECT test1 FROM __new );
```

But with both triggers I get the error the fieldB cannot be null.
So - how could I populate a field with a not null constraint with a trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't.

The NOT NULL constraint is checked **before** any triggers are executed!

You would have to lift the constraint and make sure that the value is not null in a INSERT and UPDATE trigger to simulate your desired behavior.

Another workaround is to set the default value for the field `test2` to some dummy value (can be done using the table editor or `sp_ModifyFieldProperty`).

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?master_sp_modifyfieldproperty.htm

Comment: Hi Jens, I thought that the constraint is validated before the trigger - thanks for conforming this.